# Filter unwanted characters from string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want an easier way to filter out unwanted characters from a string using a white-list in PowerShell. In this case, I just want alphanumeric and spaces. Here's what I have so far (and it works), but it seems like there must be a little trick that doesn't require an extra variable:

```
$tmp = ''
[regex]::Matches($str, '[\w ]+') | ForEach-Object { $tmp += $_.Groups[0].Value }
$str = $tmp
```

Comment: `-join [regex]::Matches($str, '[\w ]+')` or `$str -replace '[^\w ]+'`.

Comment: the regex above includes `_`, just so you know

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the characters you don't want in the string by inverting the [character class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) and using the [`-replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operator:

```
$str = $str -replace '[^\w ]+'
```

Note that `\w` includes the underscore character (`_`). If you want that removed as well you need to change the regular expression to `[^a-z0-9 ]`. Since PowerShell is case-insensitive by default you don't need to explicitly include uppercase letters unless you want to use the case-sensitive replacement operator (`-creplace`). In that case change the regular expression to `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`.

Comment: If you want to remove `_` but keep not English letters, then you can use `[^ -[\w-[_]]]+` regex.